# Keeping track of text position on pdf using FPDF and GetY

Tags: fpdf

I am trying to keep track of the current Y position on a `PDF` page created using `FPDF` so that I can correctly start a new page ensuring tables do not cross a page break. Firstly am I right in using `GetY` to monitor this and if so what is the correct syntax. I am trying

```
$currentYposition = GetY();
```

but it does not seem to work. Any advice?

Comment: Is this your full code? - I'm just wondering if you're calling GetY() on your PDF object (e.g. `$pdf->GetY()` ) or just like this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why this works - but it does:
If you just grab Y after the call, it seems to be the value before the MultiCell.
Grabbing it before and after and taking the difference gives you the height.

```
$oldY = $this->getY();
$this->MultiCell(150, 4, utf8_decode($description), 0, "L");
$newY = $this->getY();

$multiCellHeight = $newY-$oldY;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.

```
$y = $pdf->GetY();
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question when programming in python and using the fpdf module. I'll post in case anyone else need this, I could not find this solution in the official documentation but for me following worked:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF() 
pdf.add_page()
current_y = FPDF.get_y(pdf)
```